# Bluetooth not working, cannot turn on

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth adapter that worked fine on win 10. But I cannot enable it on fresh installed PopOS. It's just always off.

Model https://ks-is.com/adaptery-i-perehodniki/usb-bluetooth-5-0-adapter-ks-is-ks-457

systemctl status bluetooth shows active status

lsusb results

Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio

```
❯ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE SOFT HARD
4 bluetooth hci0 unblocked unblocked

❯ hcitool dev
Devices:

❯ hciconfig -a
hci0: Type: Primary Bus: USB
BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 ACL MTU: 0:0 SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN
RX bytes:21 acl:0 sco:0 events:2 errors:0
TX bytes:6 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0
Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1
Link policy:
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

**What's written in official docs about linux**

KS-is KS-457 Bluetooth 5.0 USB Adapter

Requirements to install and use this model under Linux

It is identified by lsusb as 0bda: 8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Linux support

a. The adapter is supported by bt_trl (CONFIG_BT_RTL, starting with Linux 5.8. Firmware is required for the driver. Firmware is available in the linux-formware package starting April 2020.

b. You will need to upgrade your kernel to version 5.8+ if you have an older kernel and want to use this adapter.

c. The recommended version is Linux 5.8.1

AUR package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8761b-fw/

Comment: So did you install that firmware ? and verified your kernel version (just run `uname -r`)

Comment: ❯ uname -r
5.11.0-7620-generic

Comment: I didn't install this AUR package, as I thought it's related to arch distros, and also that link is broken.

Comment: You may try getting config and fw files from RT open source repository. See https://github.com/Realtek-OpenSource/android_hardware_realtek  (you need to rename both files to .bin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by installing this firmware

https://linuxreviews.org/Realtek_RTL8761B

Answer (score 1):

Indeed since PopOs appears to be based on Ubuntu you correctly inferred that the AUR package does not apply here, it is for Arch Linux and derived distributions. The [manufacturer page](https://ks-is.com/usb-bluetooth-5-0-adapter-ks-is-ks-457) you linked to provides a RAR file for Linux. That archive contains a Word document that doesn't say much, and the other file is the driver.

So based on consulted articles the solution could be as "simple" as this:

- uncompress the RAR file and copy the driver to /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_bt on your computer
- also add the .bin extension so the file is named rtl8761b_fw.bin

I suggest that after installing the driver you run this command:

```
sudo dmesg -w | grep - i bluetooth
```

then unplug the device and plug it again and see from the ouput of dmesg if it can locate the driver this time.

Reference: [How to install unsupported Bluetooth 5.0 Dongle on Linux](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-install-unsupported-bluetooth-5-0-dongle-on-linux-4bf34aa99fed)

Answer (score 1):

It will work out-of-box with Linux kernel v5.19+.

### Driver

I've submitted a [patch to upstream](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/bluetooth/patch/20220427125947.10429-1-ismael@iodev.co.uk/) (merged in [`mainline`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c77a592befdd)) for these adapters. Without it, the adapters work very unreliably, at least with newer drivers/firmware, among other things they show pairing issues, specially with BLE devices.

### Firmware

Generally there's no need to download random third-party files. The required blobs are included in the [linux-firmware](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/) project, you can download it there as a last resort.

However, the best method is to install it from your distro.

Package name by distro:

| Distro | Package |
| --- | --- |
| Alpine | `linux-firmware-rtl_bt` |
| Arch | `linux-firmware` |
| Debian | `firmware-realtek` |
| Fedora | `linux-firmware` |
| Gentoo | `linux-firmware` |
| openSUSE | `kernel-firmware-realtek` |
| Slackware | `kernel-firmware` |
| Source Mage | `linux-firmware` |
| Void Linux | `linux-firmware` |

These packages are generally kept up to date, but not always, so check the version is recent, and if it doesn't include it, don't forget to let the maintainer of the package know.